# Why does Eclipse claim I have an outdated version of the ADT?

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I recently upgraded to the latest version of the Android SDK using the SDK Manager.

Unfortunately it appears as if something went wrong. Every time I launch Eclipse now, I get the following error message:

[image]

If I click "Check for Updates", Eclipse does its thing and happily reports that there are no updates to install and that everything is up to date.

I can confirm that I have the latest version of the SDK installed:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Google have aligned the release number of the Android SDK and Android Development Tools (ADT) to help developers "remember" to upgrade. To do this, every time you update the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), also update the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Eclipse won't do this for you automatically. For ADT, do it manually via **Help | Install New Software | Add button | Archive button**, and browse to the location of the downloaded ADT zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems like the problem was that I had:

> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

...instead of...

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Notice the **https://**.

Answer (score 0):

> If I click "Check for Updates", Eclipse does its thing and happily reports that there are no updates to install and that everything is up to date.

The error dialog is correct -- the latest ADT is 22.0.4. I have no idea why Eclipse's upgrade process would fail to see that, though.

Push come to shove, you may need to uninstall and reinstall the ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Eclipse plugin itself:

Help-> check for updates.

If that doesnt work (as is usual), try loading in the update in manually by.

Help -> install new software

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

I once had this and I think I had to update/fix the link to the Android ADT 'Software Site' in Eclipse.

From the Eclipse menu:
Help > Install New Software

Then in the 'Work with' text box, click the down arrow and check to see if the Android Tools Update site is included. Mine points to:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week, I tried everything, but nothing helped me.

Finally fixed it only by re-downloading ADT bundle whole again.